# common io copyUrlToFile not working

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, apache-commons, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to call my web service which return a csv file. So each URL I call has a suffix which is a string which says which csv to generate. I want to then save this csv to a file. There are many to be generated so I am calling this class from multiple threads. Every time I run the program the amount of files returned upon completion is a different amount. The webservice is running fine because if I manually call a URL from a browser which did not create a file, the csv is generated and downloaded. In total there are about 15,000 URL's which are called by 12 threads. I receive no errors in the output console, just says the build was successful. Usually about 1500-2000 files are generated each run instead of 15000. I am using apache's common io FileUtils library to save the url to a file.

```
final int maxRetries = 5;
HistoryWebservice historyWS = new HistoryWebservice();
String history = historyWS.getHistory(maxRetries);

public class HistoryWebservice {
    public String getHistory(int maxRetries, String str) throws Exception {
        maxRetries = Math.max(0, maxRetries); //Make sure we don't have a negative retry counter

        while (maxRetries >= 0) {
            try {
                FileUtils.copyURLToFile("http://myservice.myservice/" + str, "/tmp/file" + str);
            }
            catch(<Catch the timeout exception>) {
                maxRetries--;
            }
        }

        throw new TimeoutException("Max retries exceeded");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the open files allowed on UBUNTU 14.04. The default is 2096 so with the command ulimit -n 100000 it is now running fine.